# Django Rest Framework Browsable API [No Renderers Found]

Tags: django-rest-framework

Any advice on why this happens?

[image]

This is my view. Note that I do specify the render_classes as JSONRenderer.

```
class RetailCustomerGetView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    render_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    queryset = RetailCustomer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RetailCustomerSerializer
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        customer_count = RetailCustomer.objects.count()
        content = {'customer_count':customer_count}
        return Response(content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the renderer in the DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES in my projects settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer','rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer']        # added JSONRenderer here
}
```